# Make a spaghetti plot in R with several groups and categorical x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need your help. I need to make a spaghetti plot. I have categorical variables (months) on the x-axis, and on the y-axis, I have abundance data (numeric). How can I order each group (species) so that it starts from 0 on the y-axis??? Also, I need help to assign different colors to each group. Thank you!!

I use this example published on this page, but the order of the groups (ID) is done from the x-axis, which is numerical, and I need to order it from the y-axis. I had tried several ways without success. I would appreciate it if you could help me!

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

# your data

df <- data.table(ID = c(1,1,2,2,2,3),
                 Result = c(70,80,90,89,99,23),
                 Days = c(0,23,15,30,40,24))

# adjust each ID to start at day 0, sort 

df <- merge(df, df[, list(min_day = min(Days)), by = ID], by = 'ID')
df[, adj_day := Days-min_day]
df <- df[order(ID, Days)]

# plot

ggplot(df, aes(x = adj_day, y = Result, color = factor(ID))) +
geom_line() + 
geom_point() +
theme_bw()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including *your* code and a snippet of your *data* or some fake data.

Answer (score 0):

For clarity, do you mean to *adjust* the `Result` column to start at zero at time point 1? This code should do that:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

# your data

df <- data.table(ID = c(1,1,2,2,2,3),
                 Result = c(70,80,90,89,99,23),
                 Days = c(0,23,15,30,40,24))

# adjust each ID to start at day 0

df <- merge(df, df[, list(min_day = min(Days)), by = ID], by = 'ID')
df[, adj_day := Days-min_day]

# adjust each result to start at 0

df <- df[order(adj_day)]
df[, `:=`(adj_result = Result - first(Result)), 
   by = .(ID)]

ggplot(df, aes(x = adj_day, y = adj_result, color = factor(ID))) +
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Using `order()` on a dataframe changes the order the rows are in, but if you're not doing any other changes then it doesn't change the way it's plotted.

Or you mean to *order* the IDs by starting value - i.e. making the legend rank the IDs in order of lowest to highest starting value?

### Doing it with months

Here's some simulated data which may demonstrate how to start y values at zero when plotting across months:

```r
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

dt2 <- data.table(
  ID = rep(1:5, each = 5),
  month = rep(month.name[1:5], times = 5),
  result = sample(20:100, 25, replace = TRUE)
)

dt2[,`:=`(month = factor(month, levels = month.name[1:5]))]
dt2 <- dt2[order(month)] 
dt2[,`:=`(adj_result = result - first(result)), by = .(ID)]

ggplot(dt2, aes(month, adj_result, colour = factor(ID), group = ID)) +
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

### Months but no negative numbers

To get no negative numbers, use the values themselves rather than the adjusted values (`animal.number` minus January's `animal.number' gives zero in January but for species 2 gives -27 in June).` animal.number` needs to be transformed to a numerical value (rather than string) for this to work:

```r
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

dt2 <-
  data.table(
    ID = rep(c("species1", "species2", "species3"), each = 6),
    month = rep(month.name[1:6], times = 3),
    animal.number = c(
      "0", "2", "1", "5", "0", "0",
      "67", "200", "83", "115", "120", "40",
      "0","2","0","4","12","1"
      )
  ) 

dt2[,`:=`(month = factor(month, levels = month.name[1:6]),
          animal.number = as.integer(animal.number))]

ggplot(dt2, aes(month, animal.number, colour = factor(ID), group = ID)) +
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point() +
  ylim(0, NA) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: THANKS A LOT!!!!!! The month's example is what I need... Just one more thing... I need no negative numbers in adj_results because I work with numbers of animals and there can only be positive numbers. Can you help me adjust that? Thanks again!!

Comment: Other question... I get this error when I use my data:
 dt2[,`:=`(adj_result = result - first(result)), by = .(ID)]
Error in result - first(result) : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. If group ID 1 for example started with 100 animals in January and then had 80 in February, would you want to start this line on y=0, meaning February would be y=-20? Or would you start it on y=100 and not adjust the y value?

Comment: As to your error - your 'result' column should be a numeric column but that error would be produced if it was a character. If you are having trouble with your data you can share a sample using `dput(df)` and pasting output in your question.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering. Speaking specifically about my data, I show an example of my data so I can explain it to you. What I need to represent are the exact values of animal.number, which represent the number of animals seen in each month for each species, and there can be no negative numbers.
So the y-axis should start at 0, but it should represent the values as they are in the table for each species in each month.
And, with this data, I get the error that I mentioned.

Comment: structure(list(ID = c("species1", "species1", "species1", "species1", 
"species1", "species1", "species2", "species2", "species2", "species2", 
"species2", "species2", "species3", "species3", "species3", "species3", 
"species3", "species3"), month = c("January", "February", "March", 
"April", "May", "June", "January", "February", "March", "April", 
"May", "June", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", 
"June"), animal.number = c(0L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 67L, 200L, 
83L, 115L, 120L, 40L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 12L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))

Comment: dt2 <- data.table(ID=c("species1", ...
                                     "species2", ...
                                     "species3", ...),
                  month=c("January", ....., "June", 
                                  "January", ....., "June",
                                  "January", ....., "June",),
                  animal.number=c("0","2","1","5","0","0",
                                               "67","200","83","115","120","40",
                                                "0","2","0","4","12","1"))

Comment: Hello @Euseag - have posted edited code with your data, does this give you the graph you're looking for?

Comment: Have a merry Christmas!